# Span a record on multiple pages in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, reporting

MS Access has a limitation in its Reports functionality that is max Section height is  22.75 in. (57.79 cm). I want to create a report that will use data from a single record to span on 12 pages in a specific formatting. Right now I can not put more than 2 A4 pages in Design View. Is there someway to achieve this?

Thanks